# Unable to remove blank dict from an array in pyspark column

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a column in my DF where data type is :
--testcolumn:array
--element: map
-----key:string
-----value: string

testcolumn
**Row1:**
[{"class":"6","Roll:"1","Name":"Ram1"},{"class":"6","Roll:"2","Name":"Ram2"},{"class":"6","Roll:"3","Name":"Ram3"},{"":""},{"":""}]

**Row2:**
[{"class":"6","Roll:"1","Name":"Ram1"}]
[{"":""},{"":""}{"class":"6","Roll:"1","Name":"Ram1"},{"class":"6","Roll:"2","Name":"Ram2"},{"class":"6","Roll:"3","Name":"Ram3"}]

**Row3:**

[{"class":"6","Roll:"1","Name":"Ram1"},{"class":"6","Roll:"2","Name":"Ram2"},{"class":"6","Roll:"3","Name":"Ram3"}]

**Row4:**
[{"":""},{"":""}{"class":"6","Roll:"1","Name":"Ram1"},{"":""},{"":""}]

expecting output:
outputcolumn

**Row1:**
[{"class":"6","Roll:"1","Name":"Ram1"},{"class":"6","Roll:"2","Name":"Ram2"},{"class":"6","Roll:"3","Name":"Ram3"}]

**Row2:**

[{"class":"6","Roll:"1","Name":"Ram1"},{"class":"6","Roll:"2","Name":"Ram2"},{"class":"6","Roll:"3","Name":"Ram3"}]

**Row3:**

[{"class":"6","Roll:"1","Name":"Ram1"},{"class":"6","Roll:"2","Name":"Ram2"},{"class":"6","Roll:"3","Name":"Ram3"}]

**Row4:**
[{"class":"6","Roll:"1","Name":"Ram1"}]

I have tried this code but it is not giving me output:

```
test=df.withColumn('outputcolumn',F.expr("translate"(testcolumn,x-> replace(x,'{"":""}','')))
```

it will be really great if someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all your values remain strings, and that your data frame does look something like this:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
  {"testcolumn": [{"class":"6","Roll":"1","Name":"Ram1"},{"class":"6","Roll":"2","Name":"Ram2"},{"class":"6","Roll":"3","Name":"Ram3"},{"":""},{"":""}]},
  {"testcolumn": [{"class":"6","Roll":"1","Name":"Ram1"},{"":""},{"":""},{"class":"6","Roll":"1","Name":"Ram1"},{"class":"6","Roll":"2","Name":"Ram2"},{"class":"6","Roll":"3","Name":"Ram3"}]},
  {"testcolumn": [{"class":"6","Roll":"1","Name":"Ram1"},{"class":"6","Roll":"2","Name":"Ram2"},{"class":"6","Roll":"3","Name":"Ram3"}]},
  {"testcolumn": [{"":""},{"":""},{"class":"6","Roll":"1","Name":"Ram1"},{"":""},{"":""}]}
])

df.show(truncate=False)
# +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |testcolumn                                                                                                                                                                  |
# +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |[{Roll -> 1, class -> 6, Name -> Ram1}, {Roll -> 2, class -> 6, Name -> Ram2}, {Roll -> 3, class -> 6, Name -> Ram3}, { -> }, { -> }]                                       |
# |[{Roll -> 1, class -> 6, Name -> Ram1}, { -> }, { -> }, {Roll -> 1, class -> 6, Name -> Ram1}, {Roll -> 2, class -> 6, Name -> Ram2}, {Roll -> 3, class -> 6, Name -> Ram3}]|
# |[{Roll -> 1, class -> 6, Name -> Ram1}, {Roll -> 2, class -> 6, Name -> Ram2}, {Roll -> 3, class -> 6, Name -> Ram3}]                                                       |
# |[{ -> }, { -> }, {Roll -> 1, class -> 6, Name -> Ram1}, { -> }, { -> }]                                                                                                     |
# +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You could accomplish this by a) casting the whole column to a string with `to_json`, b) cleaning up the empty maps with `regexp_replace`, and c) casting the column back with `from_json`.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_out = df \
  .withColumn("testcolumn", F.to_json(F.col("testcolumn"))) \
  .withColumn("testcolumn", F.regexp_replace(F.col("testcolumn"), ',?\{"":""\}', '')) \
  .withColumn("testcolumn", F.regexp_replace(F.col("testcolumn"), "(?<=\[),", "")) \
  .withColumn("testcolumn", F.from_json(F.col("testcolumn"), "ARRAY<MAP<STRING, STRING>>"))

df_out.show(truncate=False)
# +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |testcolumn                                                                                                                                                  |
# +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |[{Roll -> 1, class -> 6, Name -> Ram1}, {Roll -> 2, class -> 6, Name -> Ram2}, {Roll -> 3, class -> 6, Name -> Ram3}]                                       |
# |[{Roll -> 1, class -> 6, Name -> Ram1}, {Roll -> 1, class -> 6, Name -> Ram1}, {Roll -> 2, class -> 6, Name -> Ram2}, {Roll -> 3, class -> 6, Name -> Ram3}]|
# |[{Roll -> 1, class -> 6, Name -> Ram1}, {Roll -> 2, class -> 6, Name -> Ram2}, {Roll -> 3, class -> 6, Name -> Ram3}]                                       |
# |[{Roll -> 1, class -> 6, Name -> Ram1}]                                                                                                                     |
# +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks its really help me to resolve my issue

Comment: hi Tyler Richardett : if the column is coming like [{"name":"Ram1","CLass":"5"}] how to make it [{"name":"Ram1"},{"CLass":"5"}]
is it possible to do it using regex ... It will be really great if you help me